# Angular2: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'. Error when accessing .control of an object within a formarray thru an index

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to push another formbuilder within a formarray but it gives me an error since I think there are no items in the array when initializing the code, hence there are no controls. The error is Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl' after the

```
(<FormArray>this.loanTypeForm.controls['frequency']).controls[index]
```

I'm using angular 2.0.0-beta.17

```
let settingsForm: FormArray = new FormArray([]);
      (<FormArray>this.loanTypeForm.controls['frequency']).push(
        this.formBuilder.group({
          'name': [value, Validators.required],
          'settings': settingsForm,
        })
      );
(<FormArray>this.loanTypeForm.controls['frequency']).controls[index].controls['settings'].push(
      this.formBuilder.group({
        'term': [null, Validators.required],
        'eir': [null, Validators.required],
      })
    );
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can use `['controls']` instead of `.controls`, as below:

```
(<FormArray>this.loanTypeForm.controls['frequency']).controls[index]['controls']['settings'].push(...)
```

But in order to simplify and provide more readability I'd suggest you to change it all to:

```
const control = this.loanTypeForm.get(`frequency.${index}.settings`) as FormArray;
control.push(...);
```

Comment: @user3764335 I'm glad that it helped :)

Comment: Thanks! But now I got *"object access via string literals is disallowed"*. Can be resolved by adding `"no-string-literal": false` to tslint.json's rules.

Answer (score 7):

[`get()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/AbstractControl-class.html#!#get-anchor) is the preferred way to access form controls

```ts
this.loanTypeForm.get(`frequency.${index}.settings`)
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems that the `loanTypeForm` is treated as `AbstractControl`... so let's assure compiler that it is **`FormGroup`**

```
var group = this.loanTypeForm as FormGroup;
var array = group.controls['frequency'] as FormArray;
var control = group.controls[index]; // AbstractControl again.. could be casted as needed
```

and in case, that control is also group or form we just have to use assert (cast) as well

```
var control = group.controls[index] as FormGroup
```

And then we can easily continue

```
control.controls['settings']...
```

Comment: when i try to get the control.controls['settings'] but i got "Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined".

Comment: I extended the answer with another assert.. now we expect that control is FormArray.. and we can tell that to compile (the `as` statement). In case that it is FormGroup (which controls property is dictionary not array) we just would use as FormGroup... hope it helps a bit ;)

Comment: The best answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is My solution if you are Following the **Angular Course on Udemy**

This code will fail with the latest Angular version.
You can fix it easily though. Outsource the “get the controls” logic into a getter of your component code (the .ts file):

```
get controls() { // a getter!
 return (<FormArray>this.recipeForm.get(‘ingredients’)).controls;
}
```

In the template, you can then use:

```
*ngFor="let ingredientCtrl of controls; let i = index"
```

This adjustment is required due to the way TS works and Angular parses your templates (it doesn't understand TS there)

Answer (score 0):

below code is working

```
<FormArray>this.loanTypeForm.controls['frequency']).controls[index]['controls']['settings'].push(...)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Consider adding an explanation to your code. As it stands, your answer is duplicating the first section of the accepted answer's code, and doesn't add any value.

Answer (score 0):

For those still struggling(and using `get` keyword), you just need to strongly type your return property type. I am working with dynamic controls(FormArray).

instead:

```
get optionsWidgetSettingsArray(): FormArray {
    return <FormArray>this.widgetForm.get('optionsWidgetSettings');
}
```

use:

```
get optionsWidgetSettingsArray(): FormArray<FormArray<FormControl>> {
    return <FormArray>this.widgetForm.get('optionsWidgetSettings');
}
```